# How can I install Ubuntu 14 LTS on my Dell 13" 7000 series 2-in-1 laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I've read a number of guides attempting to explain how to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10, but the problem I keep running into is that can't I can't even get the Ubuntu installer to start. I continually get an error: oxc000007b. I've tried running the WUBI installer, tried booting with the Shift+Restart command and booting from the USB device with Ubuntu installed on it, tried mounting the ISO through Windows 10's built in tool; tried changing all the UEFI settings to Legacy to normal, to secure boot enabled to disabled, etc, etc etc. I simply can't get it to boot up with the Ubuntu installer.

As implied, I'm on Windows 10, and my computer has UEFI. I miss the days of simple BIOSs where you could just run WUBI and magic would happen. Windows 10 is just so slow. I need Linux!!

Edit: I used the Unetbootin tool. I am pretty sure all the USB drives I used were FAT32; I tried a number of different drives as well.

Comment: First of all are you using a LiveCD or LiveUSB?  If a LiveUSB, what program did you use to create it?

Answer (score 1):

WUBI is deprecated even on BIOS-based computers and is 100% useless on a dual-boot with an EFI-mode Windows installation, so don't waste any more time on it.

When doing a dual-boot installation in EFI mode, you should ***NOT*** enable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka "legacy boot support" or a similar phrase). Doing so is much more likely to create problems than to solve them. At best, it will solve an early problem only to create bigger problems further down the line. For more on this subject, see [my Web page on the CSM.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

I'm unfamiliar with the 0xc000007b error you report, but my guess is that your Linux installation medium is not prepared correctly. Tools used to create USB drives are not created equal. Personally, I generally use `dd` to copy images to USB flash drives, but that's not convenient in Windows. In Windows, the [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) program seems to have the best reputation, although [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) also usually works. Contrary to dodo_master's recommendation, I see a lot of problem reports about [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) (aka PenDriveLinux and one or two other names), at least for EFI-mode installs. Unfortunately, what works well varies from one distribution and computer to another, so I can't point you at something that's 100% guaranteed to work; you may need to try two or three tools before you find one that works on *your* computer.

Comment: Can confirm that this method worked. I also followed dodo_master's suggestion to make sure it was formatted in FAT32 (I think it was before). But the Rufus program worked. I also disabled Secure Boot, and then set my UEFI to boot the USB option as the first (it didn't show up until I used Rufus), and from there the rest was simple.

Answer (score -1):

the error oxc000007b is because you have to format your usb with fat32.

then use universal usb installer to make a bootable ubuntu usb

and as you implied that you are not happy with win 10 and you missing the simple bios days then you should delete win 10 and go open source as i did. I like the freeodm of doing anything on linux. but before this transfer all your files on external hard disk Ofcourse:p